# Mysql fails to run after reboot using crontab

Tags: python, mysql, cron

I have made a script which saves data to Mysql database using mysqldp and python. When I run script from console (python myscript.py) it works, but when I run it on reboot using Crontab I get an email with following error:

> **_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")**

When I try to run the script using **Crontab** not on reboot, but accordingly to time I don't get following error.

Maybe you have some ideas?

What if I would call the same script with `while(1)` loop once and once again (It will start the new background task every time)?

Comment: Which crontab are you using to run the command? Usually you have to be root in order to reboot mysqld.

Comment: That is the crontab I usePATH=/home/pi/Documents/stafor:/usr/bin:/var/run/mysql
MAILTO=antons.osadchijs@gmail.com
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/stafor/data.py

Comment: Perhaps the MySQL daemon has not started yet when the script was run.

Comment: @AntonOsadchy I didn't mean the crontab rule, but the user that runs the crontab.

Comment: Hmmmm, I haven't specified it at all. Do you know how can I check it out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shadow's hint I have solved the problem.
I just have started the **Mysql** server manually from the script and now it works.

I have used this command to start the server

> **from subprocess import call**
>
> **call(['sudo','service','mysql','start'])**